# Find $\epsilon'$ s.t $L_\epsilon$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard for any $\epsilon<\epsilon'$

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, approximation

Let $L_\epsilon$ be the language of all $2$-CNF formulas $\varphi$, such that at least $(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)$ of $\varphi$'s clauses can be satisfied.

I need to prove that there exists $\epsilon'$ s.t $L_\epsilon$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard for any $\epsilon<\epsilon'$.

We know that $\text{Max}2\text{Sat}$ can be approximate to $\frac{55}{56}$ precent of the clauses from a $\text{Max}3\text{Sat}$ reduction. How should I solve this one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In his famous paper, [Håstad](http://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/optimalinap.ps) shows that it is NP-hard to approximate MAX2SAT better than $21/22$. This likely means that is is NP-hard to distinguish instances which are $\leq \alpha$ satisfiable and instances which are $\geq (22/21) \alpha$ satisfiable, for some $\alpha \geq 1/2$. Now imagine padding an instance so that it becomes a $p$-fraction of a new instance, the rest of which is exactly $1/2$-satisfiable (say it consists of groups of clauses of the form $a \land \lnot a$). The numbers now become $1/2 + p (\alpha - 1/2)$ and $1/2 + p((22/21)\alpha - 1/2)$. The latter number can be made as close to $1/2$ as we want.

Comment: Does your method works when ε is an arbitrary (but sufficiently small) real number?  I cannot figure out how to choose the appropriate number of clauses to use for padding unless I assume something about ε.  (Note that ε is not part of the input, and therefore it is well-defined to consider real number ε.)

Comment: That's where the gap between $1/2+p(\alpha-1/2)$ and $1/2+p((22/21)\alpha-1/2)$ could be useful. Assuming $\alpha$ is rational, take some rational $p$, and you should do fine.

Comment: Aha, somehow I thought that that method did not work when I tried it first, but now I see how it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you know that *ε* is a rational number, then you do not need inapproximability for Max-2-SAT to prove your statement.  A typical proof of the NP-hardness of Max-2-SAT (e.g., the one in the textbook *Computational Complexity* by Papadimitriou) actually proves the NP-completeness of *L*<sub>1/5</sub>.  To prove the NP-hardness of *L*<sub>*ε*</sub> for positive rational numbers *ε*<1/5, we can reduce *L*<sub>1/5</sub> to *L*<sub>*ε*</sub> as follows: given a 2CNF formula *φ* (an instance for *L*<sub>1/5</sub>), let *m* be the number of clauses in it.  Let *r* and *s* be positive integers such that (1/5−*ε*)*mr* = 2*ε**s* holds.  Then construct a 2CNF formula (an instance for *L*<sub>*ε*</sub>) by repeating *φ* for *r* times and adding *s* pairs of contradicting clauses.  A simple calculation shows that this is indeed a reduction from *L*<sub>1/5</sub> to *L*<sub>*ε*</sub>.

This reduction clearly works only if *ε* is rational, because otherwise *r* and *s* cannot be taken as integers.  The general case where *ε* is not necessarily rational seems to require inapproximability, as Yuval Filmus wrote in his answer.